# Iterator behaviour unexpected

Tags: python, python-2.7, imdb, imdbpy

I'm using the IMDbPY library to scrape details for a large number of movies when I came across the following strange behaviour

```
import imdb

s_result = ia.search_movie('"Jobs"')
movie = s_result[0]
ia.update(movie)

for x in xrange(3):
    print movie['cast'][x]
```

The output is:

```
>>Ashton Kutcher
  Dermot Mulroney
  Josh Gad
```

Which is good, but when I try and use an iterator:

```
print [movie['cast'][x] for x in xrange(3)]
```

The output is:

```
>>>[<Person id:0005110[http] name:_Kutcher, Ashton_>, <Person id:0000551[http] name:_Mulroney, Dermot_>, <Person id:1265802[http] name:_Gad, Josh_>]
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, first one is displaying the `__str__` version of the object and second one is displaying `__repr__` version.

Comment: You are mixing up `__str__` and `__repr__. I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere.